# Why my tables are not joining

Tags: sql, sas

I am not sure why my tables are not joinng. I have created an example and the tables should join but I am not sure what is causing the issue.

```
   data Master1;
   length region $30;
   input region;
   datalines;
SANFRANCISCO-OAKLAND-SANJOSE
run;

data map;
   length market $30 code $1;
   input market code;
   datalines;
SANFRANCISCO-OAK-SANJOSE A
SEATTLE B
run;

data master1;
set master1;
region=scan(region,1,'-');
run;


proc sql noprint;
   create table a as
   select a.*, b.Code,b.market
   from Master1 a 
   left join map b
   on a.region like '%' || trim(b.market) || '%';
quit;
```

Comment: If this is related to the earlier question you asked, I think you have changed the rules.  I suggest editing this question (or start over with a new one) and explain exactly what you are trying to do.  Just saying "my tables are not joining" is not sufficient.  Your tables **ARE** joining; show the result you want to get.  And don't redefine your `master1` dataset; create it once in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's substitute in the values that you have in the data, in the `where` clause:

```
a.region --> 'SANFRANCISCO-OAKLAND-SANJOSE'
b.market --> 'SANFRANCISCO-OAK-SANJOSE'
```

They are not *like* each other.  One has "OAKLAND", the other "OAK".  You need to fix the data.

EDIT:

After stripping the results you have:

```
a.region --> 'SANFRANCISCO'
b.market --> 'SANFRANCISCO-OAK-SANJOSE'
a.region like '%' || trim(b.market) || '%' --> 'SANFRANCISCO' LIKE '%SANFRANCISCO-OAK-SANJOSE%'
```

This is still false.  You have the comparison in the wrong order.  Try this:

```
 b.market like '%' || trim(a.region) || '%'
```

Comment: But I am stripping only the first word from region, SANFRANCISCO and checking if it is like SANFRANCISCO-OAK-SANJOSE which it should be because I am using the like statement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't create `LIKE '%...%'` statement (with metacharacters `%`) as a character expression.

If `region` is always a **substring** of `market`, you can use condititon

```
on index(b.market,trim(a.region))>0;
```

instead of `LIKE`.